# How many ways can an integer $i$ appearing in a sequence with multiplicty at least $j$, be minimal

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, probability-theory

Let us construct an integer sequence of length $n$, where the integers are chosen from $\{1, 2, ..., k\}$, with i.i.d. uniform probability $\frac{1}{k}$. I want to compute the probability ($p_{ij}$) that the integer $i$ ($1 \leq i \leq k$) appears *at least* $j$ times ($1 \leq j \leq n$) **and**  $i$ is the minimal integer in the sequence (*i.e.*, all other integers are $\geq i$). For example, if $k=3, n=2$, then we can easily enumerate the sequences to find that the $k\times n$ matrix $\{p_{ij}\}$ is

$$ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{5}{9} & \frac{1}{9}\\
\frac{3}{9} & \frac{1}{9}\\
\frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9}
 \end{pmatrix} $$

Since the total number of possible sequences is $k^{n}$, hence $p_{ij} = \frac{\text{to be determined function of $i$ and }j}{k^{n}}$. So the question is how to compute the numerator (number of favorable outcomes), *i.e.*, how do we **count** the number of ways that the integer $i$ appears at least $j$ times in the sequence while all other elements being $\geq i$. Any help or hints will be appreciated.

I am really interested in the general case when the integers are chosen according to a known probability vector $\{q_{1}, q_{2}, ..., q_{k}\}$, but decided to understand the uniform case first.

Comment: Greg's answer below settles the case for i.i.d. uniform choice of integers from $\{1, 2, ..., k\}$. The same argument seems to work if the integers are chosen i.i.d. according to a (known) non-uniform probability vector $\{q_{1}, q_{2}, ..., q_{k}\}$, giving $$ p_{ij} = \displaystyle\sum_{j\leq e \leq n} \begin{pmatrix} n\\ e\end{pmatrix} q_{i}^{e}  \displaystyle\sum_{i\leq i_{1} \leq i_{2} \leq ... \leq i_{n-e} \leq k} q_{i_{1}}q_{i_{2}}...q_{i_{n-e}} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of sequences in which the minimal integer $i$ appears *exactly* $e$ times is
$$
\binom ne (k-i)^{n-e},
$$
since there are $\binom ne$ ways to decide where the $i$s go and $k-i$ choices of larger integers for each other spot. The quantity you want is then the sum of this over all $e\ge j$. Equivalently,
$$
p_{ij} = \frac1{k^n} \sum_{j\le e\le n} \binom ne (k-i)^{n-e}.
$$

Comment: Thanks Greg. In the index of the sum, did you mean $j \leq e \leq n$?

Comment: That's what I wrote - wait. What? That's what I *should* have written! Now it's what I wrote.